# Hover a String in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog, highline

Hello i have a problem for my App. I develop a Online Shopping List for some friends and my family. It works finde but i would implement a new function.

I add a `listview.setOnItemClickListener` in my code.

And here comes my Question

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String value = (String)adapter.getItem(position);

               }
        });
```

How can i set a `AlertDialog`, that ask the user to highline the 'value' - article?

My `listView` use the normal `adapter`, no custom adapter and fills the content with a layout ressource.

Comment: @Gopal can you share all code

Comment: You can follow my answer below @Lyan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to redirect users to choose:

```
private final Context context=this;

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                context);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Please choose");
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Please select "+value)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Select"+value+article,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, close
                        // current activity
                        MainActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
```